# Añadir alerta Javascript a HTML, sin usar funciones

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que aparezca una alerta cada vez que le doy al boton de "saludar", ¿se podría hacer sin usar funciones en javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>HTML</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extensionjs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="alerta">saludar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('alerta').onclick = function(){
        alert('HOLA MUNDO');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "sin funciones"? Javascript opera con funciones, complicado usarlo sin ellas.

Comment: Me refiero a si existe otra forma de que salga una alerta al pulsar el boton, sin usar document.getElementById.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es `<button onclick="alert('HOLA MUNDO');" id="alerta">saludar</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById` sirve para detectar un objeto HTML. Digamos que el HTML es sólo la estructura, y el JS sirve para editar esa estructura y su funcionamiento.

Por lo tanto, el usar `document.getElementById` sólo sirve para identificar qué elemento quieres editar. En este caso, le estás diciendo que, cuando se haga clic a ese elemento, ejecute algo (en este caso, el alert). ¿Cómo lo logras?

```
// Aquí seleccionamos el elemento   Al hacer clic     Haz esto
v-------------------------------v v---------------v v----------v
document.getElementById('alerta').onclick          = function(){
        alert('HOLA MUNDO');
    }
```

Por lo tanto, lo que pase dentro del `function()` se ejecutará cuando se haga clic.

En tu caso, buscas cómo hacer lo mismo pero sin usar JS. Tal como @kosmosan ha explicado, la otra forma de hacerlo es así:

```
<button id="alerta" onclick="alert('hola mundo')">saludar</button>
```

En este caso, lo estás insertando directamente en el HTML (le estás diciendo qué hacer cuando el evento `onclick` se active). De hecho, es lo mismo que hacías en el JS, buscabas el elemento y luego explicabas qué hacer cuando se hiciera clic al elemento.

Pero, como @kosmosan dijo, no es recomendable. Además, si deseas ejecutar dos cosas al hacer clic, el tema se complica mucho. Por lo tanto, es mejor usar el método que tú usaste.

Comment: Gran ayuda gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un evento en línea, aunque no se recomienda:

```
<button id="alerta" onclick="alert('hola mundo')">saludar</button>
```